# Using start command in msconfig

Tags: batch-file

The following command works just great as the only line in a batch file:

```
start "Google Sync" /belownormal "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" /autostart
```

When I drop that line into msconfig startup tab, however, nothing happens.

So I thought maybe I needed to put in the full path to start.exe. Assuming it was an exe, that is.

So I tried both DIR and WHERE to locate start.* but nothing came up.

So, two 2uestions.

1. Is start a separate START.EXE executable in W7Pro and if so where is it?
2. How can I get this line to work inside msconfig?

Before you ask, my underlying purpose is to start Google Backup and Sync in the same way it usually does, but with /BELOWNORMAL priority. I already tried adding /BELOWNORMAL to the line Google was originally using in msconfig, without success. But START does what I want from a batch file and so I assume it would, or should, work via msconfig.

Thanks.

Comment: `START` in an internal command that is part of `CMD.EXE`.

Comment: Further to the comment above, enter `cmd /?` at the command prompt, to find out how to use it correctly for your intended task.

Comment: Thank you; that is exactly what I needed to know, and also thanks to AlexP for the coding recommendation below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use commands implemented by Cmd.exe you must invoke Cmd.exe:

```
cmd /c start "Google Sync" /belownormal "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" /autostart
```